# If a Dirichlet problem is solved by transforming into ODE (proving its radial symmetry) how can we study it on manifold?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde

If a Dirichlet problem (elliptic PDE, in $R^{n}$) is solved by  transforming into ODE (proving its radial symmetry) how can we study it on manifold?

For example, $B$ is the unit ball in $R^{n}$, the Gelfand problem is

$$
\left\{\begin{aligned}
-\Delta u & =\lambda e^u & & \text { in } B, \\
u & =0 & & \text { on } \partial B,
\end{aligned}\right.
$$

it can be transformed into

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
r^{-(N-1)}\left(r^{N-1} u^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}+\lambda e^u=0 \\
u(0)=a \quad u^{\prime}(0)=0,
\end{array}\right.
$$

if we have proved its radial symmetry, then we can study this ODE to get some results for the original PDE, I wonder if this process can be applied on the manifold, for example, compact riemannian manifold M without boundary
$$
-\Delta u=\lambda e^u \quad \text { on } M.
$$

Comment: The answer will depend entirely on whether the Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ itself has spherical/rotational symmetry ("radial symmetry" as you wrote).

Comment: I‘m a little confused about the definition of the spherically symmetry Riemannian manifold, in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4044861/book-on-the-geometry-of-rotationally-symmetric-riemannian-manifolds there are some useful discussions.

Comment: If the Riemannian manifold does not have spherical symmetry, it's unlikely that harmonic functions will have that symmetry. Spherical symmetry is simply [an action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group_action) of the [orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group) by isometries.